# Returning a count of 0 when table is null

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've been struggling to return a table which shows the ArticleID, and the total number of comments on that article. With everything I try, the results only show ArticleIDs that have at least 1 comment.

This is the current Query I'm using, I've tried using `COALESCE(Count(Comments.commentID), "0")` as well and every variation of Count/Count Distinct, 0, "0" etc, but the results keep omitting articles with 0 comments. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT Comments.articleID, COUNT(DISTINCT Comments.commentID) AS coms 
FROM Comments 
GROUP BY articleID 
ORDER BY articleID DESC)
```

Comment: If this portion of the ER-d where spoken in English, would you hear this: for every Article there are zero or more Comments? If the answer is Yes and you want to see all Articles, then you have to query Article and outer join Comments.

Comment: comments table may have articelid(s) but no comments?

Comment: *the results only show articleIDs that have at least 1 comment* because the table Comments contains only articleIDs that have at least 1 comment. If you want all articleIDs you should select from the table which contains all articleIDs.

Comment: you need to edit your question, show all table DDL, sample data,

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the article tabke as well, to get all results

```
CREATE TABLe Articles (articleID int)
```

```
INSERT INTO Articles VALUES(1),(2)
```

```
CREATE TABLe Comments(articleID int, commentID int)
```

```
SELECT a.articleID, COUNT(DISTINCT c.commentID) AS coms 
    FROM Articles a LEFT JOIN Comments c ON a.articleID = c.articleID
    GROUP BY a.articleID 
    ORDER BY a.articleID DESC
```

| articleID | coms |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cjPA_Kd0)